# How can I load an array of json objects in three.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, three.js, raytracing

Ok, so the asynchronous behavior of the loader is what is throwing me off. Here's what I have:

```
for( i = 0; i < 37; i++ ){
    partLoader.load( "parts/" + filename[i], function ( geometry ) {
        var partMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, basicMat );
        partMesh.position.y = yPos;
        partMesh.position.x = xPos;
        bodyPart.push(partMesh);
        rayCastScene.add( partMesh );
    });
}
```

Originally I was setting `bodyPart[i] = partMesh` but by the time the callback ran i = 36 and all of them just overwrote each other in the last element. Pushing them at least gets them all in the array, but I have no idea which index goes with which element anymore.

I'm using this with raytracing to identify a particular object.`if(SELECTED == bodyPart[i]) ...`

Similar problem here, but no solution: [THREE.JS loading an array of STL Meshes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496250/three-js-loading-an-array-of-stl-meshes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actualy this is not about Three.js, problem in logic, simple example:

```
    (function request(){

        $.ajax({
            url: "your path",
            data: "your data",
            timeout: "max respones time from the server in milliseconds"
        })
        .done(function(response){

              //do something with response
              request(); //call request function again
         });

    })();
```

you can create simple counter to control how much times this function will runs

Comment: I don't understand I guess. How would this work in my context?

Comment: you loaded something async, so your for end faster then ajax completed, so you need make next iteration only when first one is ended or you will get what you get)