# three.js - Adding to scene from array of mesh - t is undefined in three.js - what am i missing?

Tags: javascript, arrays, three.js, webgl

I got rid of all my fluff to make this example and hoping it makes it easier for you to help me.

https://decadent3d.s3.amazonaws.com/help1.html

https://decadent3d.s3.amazonaws.com/help2.html

The only difference between the two is, scene.add() is commented out.

I create arrays of geometry, materials, then meshes.  Everything looks good, the mesh is mesh. but adding to scene is a no go.  Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

[screencap_of_inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Y0j.jpg)

best,
newb

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a reply by -Sammy to this post...
[THREE.JS loading an array of STL Meshes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496250/three-js-loading-an-array-of-stl-meshes)

my solution is a much smaller code block, each mesh and material is added, assigned a name in sequence, and pushed to mesh and material arrays.
Thanks -Sammy

```
const loader = new THREE.STLLoader();   
const meshArray = [];
const matArray = [];
const fileList = ["https://decadentlab.s3.amazonaws.com/cases/001/Upper.stl", "https://decadentlab.s3.amazonaws.com/cases/001/Lower.stl", "https://decadentlab.s3.amazonaws.com/cases/001/Mockup.stl", "https://decadentlab.s3.amazonaws.com/cases/001/Ideal.stl" ];

var callback = function ( geometry ) { 
    const matColors = ["0xE2D4B7", "0xAF9164", "0x437C90", "0x9EBC9E", "0xFCAB64", "0xAE8799", "0x496DDB", "0x717EC3", "0xC95D63", "0xF2AF29"];
    var mats = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: matColors[i],
    specular: 0x555555,
    shininess: 10
    });
    mats.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
    mats.transparent = true;
    mats.opacity = 1;
    mats.name = "material" + i;
    matArray.push( mats );
    console.log( mats );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mats );
    mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    mesh.rotation.set(5.5, 0, 0);
    mesh.name = "mesh" + i;
    meshArray.push(mesh);
    console.log( mesh );
    scene.add( mesh );
    i++;
    if (i < fileList.length)  // put the next load in the callback
        loader.load( fileList[i], callback ) ;
};

i = 0;
loader.load( fileList[i], callback );
```